# Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

After adding to my DTO object, I want to send a list to the server

```
private ImmutableList<T> elementsToAdd;
```

from

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
```

When sending an object to the controller it throws

```
2018-06-04 21:41:31.645  WARN 508 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.jonki.popcorn.common.dto.request.ContributionNewRequest<com.jonki.popcorn.common.dto.movie.Language>]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList, contains [simple type, class com.jonki.popcorn.common.dto.movie.Language]]
```

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/tree/master/guava

Comment: Jackson needs a concrete type to work with, not T.

Comment: Can not I do ```ImmutableList``` for a generic type? But Jackson recognizes what's under the generic type ```[collection type; class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList, contains [simple type, class com.jonki.popcorn.common.dto.movie.Language]]```.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Jackson so it can serialize / deserialize Guava's imutable collections. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/tree/master/guava.

Comment: I added dependence https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-guava/2.9.5, I registered the module https://pastebin.com/4s4MvMMT And then the same.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong with so little info. Can you share more of your code?